# Google App Script- Copy rows to spreadsheet based on value while retaining hyperlink

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am a beginner with JavaScript and have been taking courses for a few months. I have a couple of scripts I have written so far that are up and running. I have an issue that I can’t get past which is very important to find a resolution for, so I’m hoping someone can help.

I have google survey’s that are being submitted and an on even form generator script that creates a form and produces a link in google sheets. The problem I’m having is that I need to be able to filter forms that belong to certain person on to a different spreadsheet using a script. I have written the script a few ways to try to achieve this but have been unsuccessful. The script works as intended but it removes the form generator links when it’s copied or moved.

Here is the filter script I had written:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var trn = ss.getSheetByName('Hull - NY');
  var originalData = trn.getRange(2, 1, trn.getLastRow() - 1, 12).getValues();
  var centerManager = 'Brooks, Robert';
  if (trn.getColumn() == 3 && trn.getValue() == 'Brooks, Robert') {
    var r = originalData.getRow();
    var data = originalData.filter(function (item) {
      return item[1] === centerManager;
    });
    var targetSheet = ss.insertSheet(centerManager);
    targetSheet.getRange(2, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data).getLastRow();
  }
}
```

I appreciate any help that could be provided!

Comment: There is no getColumn(), or getValue() method in Class Sheet So this line `if (trn.getColumn() == 3 && trn.getValue() == 'Brooks, Robert') {` does not work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must [read the formulas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformulas) and then use the formula instead of the cell value, where a formula exist.

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const trn = ss.getSheetByName('Hull - NY');
  const sourceRange = trn.getDataRange()
  const originalValues = sourceRange.getValues();
  const originalFormulas = sourceRange.getFormulas()

  const centerManager = 'Brooks, Robert';
  const MANAGER_COL = 2
  const data = []
  originalValues.forEach((row,i)=>{ 
    if(row[MANAGER_COL-1] === centerManager){
      originalFormulas[i].forEach((formula,i)=>{
        if(formula[i]){
          row[i] = formula
        }
      })
      data.push(row)
    }
  });
  const targetSheet = ss.insertSheet(centerManager);
  if(data.length>0){
    targetSheet.getRange(2, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data).getLastRow();
  }
}
```

Comment: I did not check on that, I just skipped over it Fixed. Now it should work. Assumption is that the `centerManager` is to be found in column 2. If other column, change the MANAGER_COL value

Comment: Thanks for the response GoranK! I made these changes and for some reason the formula I need to retain is still showing as the displayed value and missing the formula. The formulas I need to keep are all in one column in the original data.

Comment: Actually I just figured out why and it is working as it should! Thank you!